# RestyGWT- custom url mapping for spring rest service

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, gwt, resty-gwt

I have problem that my Spring Rest Controllers is mapped other way than RestyGWT would like.
My application is on: `http://localhost:8080/restgwt/`

According to web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/action-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My Spring service/controller listen on:
`http://localhost:8080/restgwt/service/test`

But my RestyGWT service calls this url:
`http://localhost:8080/restgwt/restgwt/test`

And I don't know how to tell to RestyGWT to change `url`. Please help.

I know that the simplest solution would be changing in `web.xml` file servlet `url-pattern` parameter

from: `<url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>`

to: `<url-pattern>/restgwt/*</url-pattern>`

but I would like to make RestyGWT to change it's behaviour.

---

Here paste some additional code:

**TestService on GWT side**

```
package pl.korbeldaniel.restgwt.client;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import org.fusesource.restygwt.client.MethodCallback;
import org.fusesource.restygwt.client.RestService;

public interface TestService extends RestService {
    @GET
    @Path("test")
    public void getInfo(MethodCallback<TestPojo> test);
}
```

**TestService on Spring side**

```
package pl.korbeldaniel.restgwt.server;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController()
public class TestService {
    @RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody TestEntity getInfo() {
        TestEntity test = new TestEntity();
        System.out.println("Hit server for getting _1");
        return new TestEntity();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reffering to the official documentation:](https://resty-gwt.github.io/documentation/restygwt-user-guide.html)

> Configuring service root URLs
>   There are two ways to configure service root URLs which are appended with the @Path annotation property when building the final service URL. For single service root URL the Defaults.setServiceRoot(String) method can be used. When several services with different service roots are used the @Options annotation is equipped with the serviceRootKey property which can be set to read service root entries provided with the static ServiceRoots.add(String, String) method.

```
Defaults.setServiceRoot(new Resource( GWT.getModuleBaseURL()).resolve("../rest").getUri());
```

So my REST path for RestyGWT becomes http://domain-name/myGwtAppModuleName/rest/furtherPath
where furtherPath is javax.ws.rs @Path(..) value 
Putting the line directly in GIN ClientModule failed with `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.getModuleBaseURL()Ljava/lang/String`
To avoid error this I've wrapped it up

```
    public class ClientModule extends AbstractPresenterModule {
        @Override
        protected void configure(){
           //your installs and binds here
           bind(RestyGwtConfig.class).asEagerSingleton();
        }
    }

    public class RestyGwtConfig {
    static {
    Defaults
.setServiceRoot(new Resource( GWT.getModuleBaseURL()).resolve("../rest").getUri());
    }
    }
```

Comment: I've put this in `ClientModule` class, and unfortunatelly I can not compile gwt project no more. I am getting an error:`[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.getModuleBaseURL()Ljava/lang/String;` Can You Help Once more?

Comment: np, I had the same issue end just ended up putting this code block in a static { Defaults.setServiceRoot(new Resource( GWT.getModuleBaseURL()).resolve("../rest").getUri()); } block inside of my util class on client side

Comment: I've put this in static method. But still the same.

Comment: Are you using .client. packages as imports on your server? Mine are org.fusesource.restygwt.client.Defaults; and org.fusesource.restygwt.client.Resource;

Comment: No. I think I don't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103000/discussion-between---and-masterdany88).